# How to change diff side by side markers to other ones?

Tags: diff, sdiff

I use

```
diff -y <file1> <file2>
```

or

```
sdiff <file1> <file2>
```

but I can't find how to change markers from the defaults which are:

```
<
>
|
```

In particular, I would like to add a visible equality marker (as default one is a whitespace) replacing it with (for example):

```
=
```

to achieve something like:

```
ab c  | ab d
efg   = efg
```

Tried to quickly read the code at https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/ but didn't manage to find the place responsible for the markers (column delimiters).

Comment: Have you looked at `comm`? Depending on what you are trying to do, that might be a better tool. You can't use it to create patches, but it might be useful.

Comment: @terdon, yes, I have. I really looked for an option to get both differences and similarities output with my custom markers. So comm is not an option for what I looked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markers are handled in the last three functions of https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/side.c in `print_sdiff_hunk`. There’s no option to override them.

You could post-process the output, relying on the fact that for a given width, the markers will always be in the same position in the output.

Comment: good point on possibility to post-process and change the markers relying on their width-relative position.
Thanks!